# Can Mongoose Materialized Path and Mongoose Restify be used together?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I have implemented a schema/model for a recursive tree structure in Mongoose. The recursive tree structure uses today an array of children which are references to the same schema. I have also built some REST APIs for basic CRUD methods on the tree.

I would now like to refactor my implementation by using two packages that have been designed independently to do what I neeed in a more professional way:

1. mongoose-mpath - to manage my mongoose tree through a materialized path pattern,
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-mpath
2. express-restify-mongoose - to generate flexible REST interfaces for mongoose models, https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-restify-mongoose

Before I change all my code to these two new patterns, I would like to get some confirmation whether this is the right approach. In other words, a quick assessment whether I can expect that these two packages will work together flawlessly on my tree schema/model, and whether the express-restify-mongoose package will help me to expose the specific methods defined by the mongoose-mpath package as REST APIs:

The mongoose-mpath package:

- Adds and manages two fields to the schema for each node in the tree, parent and path, to manage the tree behavior. When parent is updated, it automatically updates the path field.
- This happens under the covers, through .pre hooks on the tree's schema and is called "materialized tree pattern".
- It adds specific get methods for the materialized tree, like getAncestors(), getAllChildren(), getImmediateChildren(), getChildrenTree(), getParent(), level.

Obviously, I would like those 6 get methods offered by mongoose-mpath also exposed as REST APIs!

Generating REST APIs is precisely the job of the other package, express-restify-mongoose:

- In its docs, I read that it generates REST APIs like GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH for a model
- So I assume, if I use it for my new (materialized) tree schema, it will give me such basic CRUD REST APIs.
- Under the covers, I see that it also sets up all kinds of .pre hooks etc.

My specific questions:

- Is there risk that those two packages added to my schema will interfere somehow, or can I trust that they will work gracefully together?
- Most important, is there a way to have express-restify generate REST APIs also for the 6 methods defined by the mongoose-mpath package (as listed above)?
- Will that happen automatically for all methods defined on the schema (in this case by MPath), or do I manually need to insert the code for such methods into the folders, files, and code generated by Mongoose Restify (if yes, where and how?)
- Are there other alternatives to achieve what I need? I know there are other REST generators around, but Mongoose Restify seems to be quite popular, probably for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I used to maintain express-restify-mongoose**

> Is there risk that those two packages added to my schema will interfere somehow, or can I trust that they will work gracefully together?

They should not interfere, as far as I know, express-restify-mongoose doesn't patch mongoose schemas.

> Most important, is there a way to have express-restify generate REST APIs also for the 6 methods defined by the mongoose-mpath package (as listed above)?

express-restify-mongoose only supports mongoose itself, perhaps some form of middleware or hooks could be helpful.

> Will that happen automatically for all methods defined on the schema (in this case by MPath), or do I manually need to insert the code for such methods into the folders, files, and code generated by Mongoose Restify (if yes, where and how?)

You'll have to do it manually. [`serve`](https://florianholzapfel.github.io/express-restify-mongoose/#serve) returns the URI at which the endpoints were mounted so you could use that to defined additional routes.

> Are there other alternatives to achieve what I need? I know there are other REST generators around, but Mongoose Restify seems to be quite popular, probably for a reason.

I'm not aware of any but perhaps someone else can chip in!

Comment: Thanks for answering my questions about express-restify. I have meanwhile written code manually for the implementation of the backend REST APIs of my app. These methodes internally use a combination of Monggose and mongoose-mpath APIs. Not using an API code generator like express-restify-mongoose. If another package that automatically generates methods on top of Mongoose is in the stack (like in my case mongoose-mpath), the use of an API generator, though generally good, is of limited value.